# image display as below

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to generate this styling for displaying the image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSa6u.png):

[image]

I'm using tailwind CSS to achieve this one, I'm not able to achieve the curve at the down part by having using border radius on bottom right and left. what is the best way to achieve this design?

Comment: What makes you think that's being done with CSS, as opposed to editing the image itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use clip-path property in css. It can utilize as a crop tool that can crop your image in different shapes such as circle, ellipsis and polygon.

for your example you should define an ellipsis clip-path.

```css
img{
    clip-path: ellipse(80% 100% at 30% -6%);
}
```